# Access 2013, #Error in report. No #Error on Access 2003

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

we have an Access database over here which works fine with Access 2003 clients. On Access 2013, when generating a report, one field (Total sum) is filled with #Error instead of the sum of different values.

The strange thing is, that almost the identical formula is used to display all entries in the report. These lines are working just fine.

Our formula used to display all entries:

`=[TarifaCTCMST]+[TarifaCTCOM]+[TarifaCTCSSO]+[TarifaCTCGMDSS]+[TarifaCTCQS]+[TarifaCTCST]+[TarifaCTCDupCertTans]+[TarifaCTCDupEndoso]+[TarifaCTCEndPetroleo]+[TarifaCTCEndQuimico]+[TarifaCTCEndGas]+[TarifaCTCGuias]+[TarifaCTCotros]+[CantidadGuias]*[TarifaCTCGuias]+[Cantidadotros]*[TarifaCTCotros]+[TarifaCTCDupCarne]+[TarifaCTCCursos]+[TarifaRenewal]*[CantRenewal]+[TarifaExtensions]*[CantExtensions]+[TarifaBSTC]*[CantBSTC]+[TarifaBSTCone]*[CantBSTCone]`

Formula that should display the sum of all prices:
`=SUM([TarifaCTCMST]+[TarifaCTCOM]+[TarifaCTCSSO]+[TarifaCTCGMDSS]+[TarifaCTCQS]+[TarifaCTCST]+[TarifaCTCDupCertTans]+[TarifaCTCDupEndoso]+[TarifaCTCEndPetroleo]+[TarifaCTCEndQuimico]+[TarifaCTCEndGas]+[TarifaCTCGuias]+[TarifaCTCotros]+[CantidadGuias]*[TarifaCTCGuias]+[Cantidadotros]*[TarifaCTCotros]+[TarifaCTCDupCarne]+[TarifaCTCCursos]+[TarifaRenewal]*[CantRenewal]+[TarifaExtensions]*[CantExtensions]+[TarifaBSTC]*[CantBSTC]+[TarifaBSTCone]*[CantBSTCone])`

What could possibly be the issue?

Comment: so start debugging: check EACH of those values for #Error. if you do `anything + #Error`, the result is #error as well.

Comment: Running this query brings up input fields, asking for values. I narrowed down the issue to: [TarifaCTCotros] .
If I add this one to the query, it errors out. On the other machine its working fine still. What should I check now?

Comment: Use `Nz([FieldName],0)` to handle nulls, this is most often the issue.

Comment: I tried that as well, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up splitting the SUM like this. Not sure why, but this works:

`=Som([TarifaCTCMST]+[TarifaCTCOM]+[TarifaCTCSSO]+[TarifaCTCGMDSS]+[TarifaCTCQS]+[TarifaCTCST]+[TarifaCTCDupCertTans]+[TarifaCTCDupEndoso]+[TarifaCTCEndPetroleo]+[TarifaCTCEndQuimico]+[TarifaCTCEndGas]+[TarifaCTCGuias]+[TarifaCTCotros]) 
+Som([CantidadGuias]*[TarifaCTCGuias]+[Cantidadotros]*[TarifaCTCotros]+[TarifaCTCDupCarne]+[TarifaCTCCursos]+[TarifaRenewal]*[CantRenewal]+[TarifaExtensions]*[CantExtensions]+[TarifaBSTC]*[CantBSTC]+[TarifaBSTCone]*[CantBSTCone])`